# Can't mount Windows partition from Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, mount, windows-7

And meanwhile Windows won't start. It says I should use a disk image to fix it or something.

The error I get from Ubuntu when trying to open the Windows partition:

```
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

And when I run ntfsfix everything seem:

```
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
Going to un-mark the bad clusters ($BadClus)... No bad clusters...OK
NTFS partition /dev/sda2 was processed successfully.
```

At this point I don't even care for windows, I'd be happy just to get my data out :/

Maybe it's something to do with boot only?
Do you think you can help me fix this?